# Excel insert image macro from URL not working unless the URL has been opened first

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the following code to insert images from the URL. If there is a URL in the cell, it pastes the image and if there is not then leaves a star image which is already in the document. It worked fine for a while, however suddenly the images no longer come across unless I open the URLs of each image beforehand which can be frustrating as sometime there is quite a lot (I did not have to open them beforehand).

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the code or possibly a setting that may be blocking the URL until it is opened. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub URLPictreInsert()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim Pic As Object
    Dim lLeft As Long
    Dim lTop As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xCol = 2
    Sheets("Message Template").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    Pic.Delete
    Next Pic
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next shp
    Set Rng = Sheets("First Class").Range("E5:E500")

For Each cell In Rng
    filenam = cell
          
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
    Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
    Sheets("Message Template").Activate
    Set xRg = Cells(2, xCol)
    Pshp.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    With Pshp
        .Width = 100
        If Pshp.Height > xRg.Height Then Pshp.Height = xRg.Height
        .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
        .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
   End With
   GoTo 2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The `On Error Resume Next` statement hides all errors. Remove it and run your code again to debug.

Comment: Thanks! So I have removed the On Error Resume Next statement and ran it again. It comes up with an error "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Insert property of the Pictures class.
When I open the URL and run it again, it no longer occurs and the image is inserted correctly. Do you know any way to get around this?